# hometest.html:98 Uncaught ReferenceError: showHint is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (hometest.html:98) onclick @ hometest.html:98

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have the following problem.I am trying to make a website but I change the GET to POST in ajax.Now it is throwing the follow message:

```
hometest.html:98 Uncaught ReferenceError: showHint is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (hometest.html:98)
onclick @ hometest.html:98
```

This is showing in the console when I inspect the element and click the button Next.Do you have any idea about this problem.
Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="javascript">

cr=-1;
function showHint(str) {


    if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("chara").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                var parts = this.responseText.split('/abc');
                character = parts[0];
                pronunciation = parts[1];
                answers = parts[2];
                iid = parts[3];
                cr = parts[4];
                apant = parts[5];
                apant1 = parts[6];
                apant2 = parts[7];
                apant3 = parts[8];
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "-";
                document.getElementById("chara").innerHTML = "<h1>" + character + "</h1>";
                document.getElementById("pron").innerHTML = "<h1>" + pronunciation + "</h1>";
                //document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = answers;
                //document.getElementById("abcc").innerHTML = iid;
                document.getElementById("butt1").innerHTML ="<button type=\'button\' onclick=\"showHintp(\'"+ apant +"\',\'"+cr+"\',\'"+apant+"\',\'"+apant1+"\',\'"+apant2+"\',\'"+apant3+"\')\">" + apant + "</button>";
                document.getElementById("butt2").innerHTML ="<button type=\'button\' onclick=\"showHintp(\'"+ apant1 +"\',\'"+cr+"\',\'"+apant+"\',\'"+apant1+"\',\'"+apant2+"\',\'"+apant3+"\')\">" + apant1 + "</button>";
                document.getElementById("butt3").innerHTML ="<button type=\'button\' onclick=\"showHintp(\'"+ apant2 +"\',\'"+cr+"\',\'"+apant+"\',\'"+apant1+"\',\'"+apant2+"\',\'"+apant3+"\')\">" + apant2 + "</button>";
                document.getElementById("butt4").innerHTML ="<button type=\'button\' onclick=\"showHintp(\'"+ apant3 +"\',\'"+cr+"\',\'"+apant+"\',\'"+apant1+"\',\'"+apant2+"\',\'"+apant3+"\')\">" + apant3 + "</button>";
            }
        };

        st=1;
        //xmlhttp.open("GET", "/quiz/home.php?q=" + str+"&qr="+ cr, true);
        //xmlhttp.send();
        xhttp.open("POST", "/quiz/home4.php", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send('q=' +st +'&qr='+ cr);
    }
}


function showHintp(str,ass,app1,app2,app3,app4) {

    if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
       return;
    }else {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var kommati = this.responseText.split('/abc');
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = kommati[0];
                swsti = kommati[1];
                if(app1 == swsti){
                    document.getElementById("butt1").innerHTML = "<p style='background-color:green;'>" + app1 + "</p>";
                    document.getElementById("butt2").innerHTML = "<p style='background-color:red;'>" + app2 + "</p>";
                    document.getElementById("butt3").innerHTML = "<p style='background-color:red;'>" + app3 + "</p>";
                    document.getElementById("butt4").innerHTML = "<p style='background-color:red;'>" + app4 + "</p>";
                }else if(app2 == swsti){
                    document.getElementById("butt1").innerHTML = "<p style='background-color:red;'>" + app1 + "</p>";
                    document.getElementById("butt2").innerHTML = "<p style='background-color:green;'>" + app2 + "</p>";
                    document.getElementById("butt3").innerHTML = "<p style='background-color:red;'>" + app3 + "</p>";
                    document.getElementById("butt4").innerHTML = "<p style='background-color:red;'>" + app4 + "</p>";               
                }else if(app3 == swsti){
                    document.getElementById("butt1").innerHTML = "<p style='background-color:red;'>" + app1 + "</p>";
                    document.getElementById("butt2").innerHTML = "<p style='background-color:red;'>" + app2 + "</p>";
                    document.getElementById("butt3").innerHTML = "<p style='background-color:green;'>" + app3 + "</p>";
                    document.getElementById("butt4").innerHTML = "<p style='background-color:red;'>" + app4 + "</p>";
                }else if(app4 == swsti){
                    document.getElementById("butt1").innerHTML = "<p style='background-color:red;'>" + app1 + "</p>";
                    document.getElementById("butt2").innerHTML = "<p style='background-color:red;'>" + app2 + "</p>";
                    document.getElementById("butt3").innerHTML = "<p style='background-color:red;'>" + app3 + "</p>";
                    document.getElementById("butt4").innerHTML = "<p style='background-color:green;'>" + app4 + "</p>";
                }

            }
        };
        //xmlhttp.open("GET", "/quiz/home2.php?answ="+str+"&idi="+ass, true);
        //xmlhttp.send();

        xhttp.open("POST", "/quiz/home3.php", true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhttp.send('answ='str+'&idi='+ass);
    }
};
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="showHint(1)"  >Next</button>
<div id="chara">
<h1>tipota</h1>
</div>
<div id="pron">
<h1>pron</h1>
</div>
<div id="butt1">
</div>
<div id="butt2">
</div>
<div id="butt3">
</div>
<div id="butt4">
</div>
<div id="ans">
<h1>ans</h1>
</div>
<div id="abcc">
<h1>tpt</h1>
</div>
<div id="result">
<h1>afto to kati</h1>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can't just change `GET` to `POST`. The server resource is generally set up to expect the data one way or the other.

Comment: i have change the php file

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <script type="javascript">
> ```

This is an error that would have been picked up if you had [used a markup validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).

Your use of an unrecognised MIME type causes the browser to put the script into the DOM without passing this a JavaScript engine first.

Consequently, the function declaration never runs and `showHint` is never created as a global variable.

The MIME type for JavaScript is `application/javascript`.

If you leave the `type` attribute off entirely (which is allowed in HTML 5), browsers will default to JavaScript. This will save you some typing and let you avoid this type of error.

Comment: While this is true, the OP indicates that it was working before changing GET/POST.

Comment: @ScottMarcus — There is no way that changing the value of a string literal inside the script could cause this error. They have misidentified the change they made which caused the problem.

Comment: now i have two errors hometest.html:91 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
hometest.html:98 Uncaught ReferenceError: showHint is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (hometest.html:98)
onclick @ hometest.html:98

Comment: @mike — Now the script is being passed to the JS engine and it is reporting an error you made in the JS. `showHint` is now undefined for a completely different reason (because the JS is broken instead of the JS being ignored by the browser). Read the error message. Find the place it thinks a `)` is missing. Fix your code.